# Migrate Centos 6 to Fedora 25

Tags: centos, fedora, migration

I have a VPS server running Centos 6. Since this is quite old I would like to upgrade it to Fedora 25, preferrably without installing everything new from scratch. Is this possible somehow? While searching on the net I only found tutorials about migrating from Fedora to Centos, but not the other way round.

Comment: Why wouldn't you upgrade to Centos 7 instead of migrating to a different distro?

Comment: You can do it, probably by giving simply the fedora rpm repositories and then a forced upgrade from them. Linux doesn't really need a reinstall ever.

Answer (score 4):

There is no official way to do this. You *probably* will have to reinstall. (You can take the opportunity to translate your configuration to something like Ansible, so you could re-provision in the event of a catastrophe — along with backups, of course.)

It might be possible to do an in-place upgrade using yum and dnf and a lot of work — but I'm quite sure this will be more work than reinstalling.

Comment: +1 for the Ansible suggestion; while I think it is an extra effort in the case of a single server, it is self-documenting.

Comment: Thanks. I already kind of expected this. What is the strategy to properly move all settings and configurations to the new system, without copying unnecessary stuff? simply copying the etc folder doesn't seem like a good idea I guess.